# Android 13 image picker

Tags: android, image, picker

I have a client with Android 13 devices and the image picker with the camera selection is crucial to their business. I have several Samsung phones running Android 13 and they all have the camera selection and they work fine.  We have several more Android phones running Android 13 and the image picker will only let you select from the Gallery. Does anyone know why this would be and if there is a solution to getting back the Camera selection?

I researched everything I could find and set all the permissions to use the camera for every app on the phone. Nothing made a difference.

Comment: That stuff is controlled by the OEM.  It isn't a permissions thing, it's a what capabilities does the picker app that OEM preinstalled have thing.  If the picker doesn't have it, your only solution would be to write your own/find a library that provides one you like better.

Comment: You should have shown the used code.

Comment: List the working and not working devices would help others to give you the right answers.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a client with Android 13 devices and the image picker with the camera selection is crucial to their business

Then you should not be delegating that work to an external UI. Implement it within your app, so you can control it. You can use libraries like CameraX to help implement the camera capability, since not every device will have a camera app that plays nicely with you.

> I have several Samsung phones running Android 13 and they all have the camera selection and they work fine

Note that Samsung has thousands of models, counting the variants sold under common marketing names like "Galaxy S23". "Several" is a small fraction of the Samsung model roster.

> We have several more Android phones running Android 13 and the image picker will only let you select from the Galary. Does anyone know of why this would be

Device manufacturers can do what they wish. There can also be differences based on OS version.

Answer (score 0):

I have made one solution regarding the image and camera picker for all android versions.

I have made one project in Github which is supported in all android versions and you can select image without permission required.

Here is the link of the Github Project.

https://github.com/ParthLotia/FilePicker